# Should I learn OpenGL 1.5?

Tags: opengl

I want to start learning OpenGL with a book I have since a long time ago (Beginning openGL Game Programming) and it uses OpenGL 1.5 so my question is, should I learn OpenGL using this book and then learn a higher version? or should I start learning a higher version at once? are the same core concepts applied to higher versions?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/what-opengl-versions-to-learn-and-or-use?rq=1

Comment: "What should I learn" questions are really subjective based on your specific needs.  They're also now explicitly off topic given the [faq].

Comment: I just want to be able to learn more about 3D graphics and experiment a little with OpenGL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.** Modern OpenGL and OpenGL 1.5 have very little in common. It's better to learn the modern OpenGL directly. Here is a good online tutorial for that: [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/).

Comment: -1 While popular, this answer is just opinion. Some parts of them have very little in common, but other parts are pretty familiar. There's nothing backing up "It's better to learn...".