# Is it possible to run GLFW eventhough my graphic card(Nvidia) supports Direct3d API?

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics, graphics-programming

I have Nvidia 820M GPU installed in my windows 7 machine. In nvidia control panel it is showing it supports Direct3d API version 11. Am I able to run OpenGL applications(using GLUT,GLFW) on my machine with this configuration? see the below screenshot for configuration details.
[image: Graphic card info]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about game development.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily do it. Modern video drivers (almost) always come with OpenGL support.

DirectX 11 requires same hardware as OpenGL 4, so you will probably get at least OpenGL 4.3.

---

Based on [these](http://stats.unity3d.com/web/gpu.html) statistics, and [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31506/50555) information about equivalence of hardware requirements between different OpenGL and DirectX versions, we have approximately these numbers:

`OpenGL 1 works everywhere,`
`OpenGL 2 works on ~99.5%  PCs,` (I've recently seen an old PC without OpenGL 2 support, but they are rare.)
 
`OpenGL 3 works on   ~85%  PCs,`
`OpenGL 4 works on   ~40%  PCs.`

Comment: Have you got any citations to back them numbers up?

Comment: @Soapy See the updated answer. You're right, I shouldn't have posted any statistics based on my own guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glviewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) to see which version of OpenGL your graphics card supports and which extensions are available to use.

Comment: glviewer is showing only inbuilt intel hd 4000 graphic card information.I'm not able to see nvidia graphic card information.

Comment: That could be because your default GPU is set to use the on-board GPU.

Comment: Okay.. Then how can i see Nvidia GPU information?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1980891/setting-nvidia-graphics-card-default.html) before running glviewer.

Comment: Thanks soapy.. I found the details in this link..http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-820m/specifications